# How to wrap a div tag inside other tags and variable using php's echo function?

Tags: php

How to wrap a div tag inside other tags and variable using php's echo function?

This php code works:

```
     echo "<strong> $matches[1] </strong>" . "<p> $matches[2]  </p>";
```

But I need the above code to wrap inside a div. I tried the following code below but its not working.

```
    echo "<div>";              
    echo "<strong> $matches[1] </strong>" . "<p> $matches[2]  </p>";
    echo "</div>";
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What is the output you see?

Comment: "Not working" means what, exactly? What's the result and what did you expect?

Comment: I'm not getting no output at all..

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code above, what error do you get, what isn't working properly?

Comment: Either there's an error somewhere else on the code and you don't have error reporting on, or you're not running the correct code.

Comment: Please post more code. Perhaps your `$matches` variable is empty or not populated..

Comment: thanks everyone, it must be the css code not seeing the div.

Comment: Wait, so did you not look at the generated HTML at all?

Answer (score -3):

You need curly brackets if you want to output an array inside a string.

```
echo "<div>";
echo "<strong>{$matches[1]}</strong>"."<p>{$matches[2]}</p>";
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Not true - `"$array[foo]"` should work. In any case it would not cause the "no output at all" problem.

Comment: @patman are you sure about your answer? what's wrong with his current code? i didn't see any wrong.

Comment: Not true. [See the manual for examples.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)